# How do I change data type to fix data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get the database value of an item that i put on a listbox to display to the textbox. (vb.net)

My database table name is 'productlog', in this table has 3 columns, productid, productname, and price. I got the productname to display on a listbox that I made, now I am attempting to display the 3 columns on 3 textboxes. However, I get the "data type mismatch in criteria expression" error on my ExecuteReader line. Here's my code:

```
Public Class shop
    Dim provider As String
    Dim datafile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

 Private Sub listboxitems_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listboxitems.SelectedIndexChanged
     Dim lbconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\USER PC\Desktop\orderDB1.accdb")
     Dim lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE productid =' & listboxitems.Text & ' AND product ='" & listboxitems.Text & "' AND price =' & listboxitems.Text & '", lbconn) 
     Dim lbreader As OleDbDataReader

     lbconn.Open()

     lbreader = lbcmd.ExecuteReader() 'error appearing right here'
     While lbreader.Read
         txtproductid.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("productid")
         txtproduct.Text = lbreader.GetString("product")
         txtprice.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("price")


     End While

     lbconn.Close()

End Sub
```

Based on the other questions that I looked up, it might be because that 'productid' and 'price' are both integers and what I'm doing is for a String. I tried to remove the double quotes ('"& txtproductid.Text"') and turn them into 'txtproductid.Text', based from another question I looked up. The another answer that I saw was to convert the string into an integer -  'lbcmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@productid", ConvertInt32("txtproductid.Text"))' not sure if that's correct but I ended up getting the same error. How do I work around this error? Thanks.

UPDATED CODE:

```
Private Sub listboxitems_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listboxitems.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using lbconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\USER PC\Desktop\orderDB1.accdb")
        Using lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE productid = ? AND product = ? AND price = ?", lbconn)

            'Set your values here.  The parameters must be added in the same order that they 
            'appear in the sql SELECT command
            Dim prodidparam As New OleDbParameter("@productid", Me.txtproductid.Text)
            Dim prodparam As New OleDbParameter("@product", Me.txtproduct.Text)
            Dim priceparam As New OleDbParameter("@price", Me.txtprice.Text)

            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(prodidparam)
            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(prodparam)
            lbcmd.Parameters.Add(priceparam)

            'Open the connection
            lbconn.Open()

            Using lbreader As OleDbDataReader = lbcmd.ExecuteReader()
                While lbreader.Read
                    txtproductid.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("productid").ToString()
                    txtproduct.Text = lbreader.GetString("product")
                    txtprice.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("price").ToString()
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Price is more likely Decimal or Double not Int32

Comment: @Plutonix I put 10,15 and 20 on the price column on my three products, If it is indeed a double or a decimal, how would i change the data type?

Comment: @Plutonix i tried the Try and Catch and it didnt have any errors anymore. but i still cant get the textboxt to display the values.

Comment: So now that you have updated your code, what is the problem you are experiencing?  What data are you expecting to get back from the database?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Its a listbox that has a list of the products. what I'm trying to do is if i click a product on that list, its id, name, and price will be displayed on the textboxes. Its not showing up in the text boxes. i saw it in a youtube video and I'm trying to imitate it but using an access database.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway it does not have errors appearing btw

Comment: Looking at your code, the values that you get back from the SELECT statement would be exactly the same as the values passed in so the textboxes wouldn't really show any changes.  What _is_ showing up in the textboxes?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway nothing is showing up yet

Comment: @ChrisDunaway im trying to fetch the database values of the product and then display it to the text box when i click the product from the listbox.Like if i click an item from my listbox its price and name will display in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use string concatenation to create your SQL query as  you are doing here.  That opens you up to a sql injection hack.  Instead you should use a parameterized query.

Try something like this (not tested):

```
Using lbconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\USER PC\Desktop\orderDB1.accdb")
    Using lbcmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT productid, product, price FROM productlog WHERE productid = ? AND product = ? AND price = ?", lbconn)

        'Set your values here.  The parameters must be added in the same order that they 
        'appear in the sql SELECT command
        lbcmd.Parameters.Add("productid", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1234
        lbcmd.Parameters.Add("product", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "value of product"
        lbcmd.Parameters.Add("price", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = 999

        'Open the connection
        lbconn.Open()

        Using lbreader As OleDbDataReader = lbcmd.ExecuteReader()
            While lbreader.Read
                txtproductid.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("productid").ToString()
                txtproduct.Text = lbreader.GetString("product")
                txtprice.Text = lbreader.GetInt32("price").ToString()
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Since your code is using `OleDbConnection` you can't use named parameters.  Note the question marks in the SELECT statement which server as placeholders for the values.

Note that when using OleDb, you have to add the parameters in the same order as they appear in your sql query.

The Using ... End Using statements ensure that the connection, command and datareader are disposed properly.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit at at the add parameter part and declared prodidparam as new oledbparameter("@productid", me.txtprodid.Text) and then lbcmd.parameter.add.(prodidparam) but still nothing appears but no errors. Maybe im putting it in the wrong sub? Im putting the code in listbox selectedindexchanged?

Comment: Add your updated code to your question.  It's difficult to help without seeing it.